# Adding count also to parent categories

Tags: count

In this moment I have a code to show the count on categories, the problem is that the parent categories display always 0, insted of the sum of posts in children categories

```php
function custom_add_count_on_archive_title( $title ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if( $term instanceof WP_Term && 'category' === $term->taxonomy ) {
        $title .= ' <span>'.$term->count.'</span>';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_add_count_on_archive_title', 10, 1 );
```

What I should add to this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your code:

```php
function custom_add_count_on_archive_title( $title ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    if( $term instanceof WP_Term && 'category' === $term->taxonomy ) {
        
        $children_terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'child_of' => $term_id,
        ));
        
        $total_count = 0;
        
        if (!empty($children_terms) && !is_wp_error($children_terms)) {
            foreach ($children_terms as $child_term) {
                $total_count += $child_term->count;
            }
        }
    
        $title .= ' <span>'.$total_count.'</span>';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_add_count_on_archive_title', 10, 1 );
```

Have not tested it but theoretically it should work. What it does is gets the children of the current term. Iterates through them and totals the count of them.

Comment: Sorry but it breakes the site

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code:

```
function custom_add_count_on_archive_title( $title ) {
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
if( $term instanceof WP_Term && 'category' === $term->taxonomy ) {
    
    $children_terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'child_of' => $term_id,
    ));
    
    $total_count = $term->count;
    
    if (!empty($children_terms) && !is_wp_error($children_terms)) {
        foreach ($children_terms as $child_term) {
            $total_count += $child_term->count;
        }
    }

    $title .= ' <span>'.$total_count.'</span>';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_add_count_on_archive_title', 10, 1 );
```